# Why is the hover state of my SASS gradient mixin not working?

Tags: css, sass

I am using the following `gradient` mixin on some of the `anchors` in my Rails application:

```
@mixin gradient($color) { 
  $from: lighten($color, 5%);
  $to: darken($color, 5%);
  background-color: $color;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from($from), to($to));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  &:hover {
    $hover_color: darken($color, 5%);
    $from: lighten($hover_color, 5%);
    $to: darken($hover_color, 5%);
    background-color: $hover_color;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient($from, $to);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from($from), to($to));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient($from, $to);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  }
}
```

The `:hover` does not work though. When I hover over an `anchor` nothing changes. I would expect to see a change in color there.

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Per your edit: You didn't change the values.

Comment: OK now that you've made the correct edits, is there still a problem? I don't see `$strength` defined. Slow down a bit and look your code over.

Comment: As yes, sorry, I was too fast. I just cleaned up my code a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SASS code is fine.

`background-image` sits "on top" of `background-color`, so you aren't seeing the change.

Make this tweak, which will declare all background properties:

```
&:hover {
  background: darken($color, 20%) !important;
}
```

You can probably remove `!important`.

If you want to have a different gradient, you have to declare *each* property again (with different values) in the `:hover` styles.

Comment: Yes, that does work. But I would like to keep the gradient on the :hover state too. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Sure, but you have to set the correct properties. Add styles for `background-image` as you have done for the non-hover state. You really should use the standard `linear-gradient` as the final rule too. In addition, I'm not sure you need all those vendor-specific properties, check which versions of which browsers you actually need to support and see if they need them.

Comment: OK, I just copied those four lines over to the :hover state. But it's not working. The link / button doesn't change at all when I hover over it.

Comment: Update your post with the new code. Leave the old code so I don't look like a moron. Did you.... change the values?

Comment: Yeah as I suspected, you didn't change the to/from values, so of course you will not see a different color. (you should set the `background-color` too for browsers that don't support gradients). For your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/wgmEh/1/

Comment: Ah yes, got it. I've updated my code above and now it works. It feels a bit verbose though. I thought there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: It's verbose because of the vendor-specific rules, which as I've noted you may not need (and you aren't even using the standard `linear-gradient` which you should be)

Comment: You know, you can just use the same mixin with different parameters for the hover states instead of including hover styles in the gradient mixin itself. I think it's much better that way anyways.

Comment: Yes, I will convert those four lines into another mixin. But why do you think I don't need all of them? I am just trying to target as many browsers as possible here. And what would be the *standard* `linear-gradient`? Thanks a lot for your help by the way.

Comment: Standard is like `background: linear-gradient(topcolor, bottomcolor);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient, http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#linear-gradients

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a transparent gradient, and just changing the background color. Also, you're redefining your `$from` and `$to` variables instead of accepting a `$color` parameter.

```
@mixin gradient($color) { 
  $from: transparent;
  $to: darken($color, 5%);

  background-color: lighten($color, 5%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from($from), to($to));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient($from, $to);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient($from, $to);

  &:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed that in my initial post.